# unable to define navigate = useNavigate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to run this code:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>CLICK</button>
    <h1>HATS PAGE</h1>
  </div>
);
```

but somehow `const navigate = useNavigate()` gives me `Parsing error: Unexpected token`

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: its `navigate("/")` and not Navigate

Comment: my bad. but still the same problem

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the component. At the moment the example has too many errors to know which is the actual issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks need to be called at the top level of your React functional component.

```
function ComponentName() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>CLICK</button>
      <h1>HATS PAGE</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Exactly! I also used parentheses instead of curly braces when defining the arrow function, that was my mistake as well

Answer (score 2):

You can't put your statements which define variables **in the middle** of a JSX expression.

Define your variables first. Then do your JSX.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>CLICK</button>
        <h1>HATS PAGE</h1>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! this was half of the solution. also, I accidentally used parentheses instead of curly braces when creating the arrow function. I appreciate your response!